# I'm having trouble using docker-py in a development environment on OSX

Tags: python, macos, docker

I am creating Python code that will be built into a docker image.
My intent is that the docker image will have the capability of running other docker images on the host.

Let's call these docker containers "daemon" and "workers," respectively.

I've proven that this concept works by running "daemon" using

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

I'd like to be able to write the code so that it will work anywhere that there exists a /var/run/docker.sock file.

Since I'm working on an OSX machine I have to use the Docker Quickstart terminal. As such, on my system there is no docker.sock file.

The docker-py documentation shows this as the way to capture the docker client:

> from docker import Client
>
> cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')

Is there some hackery I can do on my system so that I can instantiate the docker client that way?

Can I create the docker.sock file on my file system and have it sym-linked to the VM docker host?

I really don't want to have to build my docker image every time I was to test a single line code change... help!!!

Comment: Docker for Mac beta DOES have a socket file.  If you're using a VM based solution (docker-machine for example) you still have the socket, it is just in the VM.  If you're using a tcp connection you can get docker-py to connect by just putting the address in, but your docker containers will have trouble getting the host ip address in order to be able to access the commands.

Comment: Seems like you might be better off using a full VM (Vagrant, VB, etc.) as the Docker host so your dev environment would be more like a production environment (assuming that's the eventual goal).

Comment: Yeah. I'd like to mount part of the VM's file system to my Mac laptop so that I can create a symlink to the docker.sock file so that I can refer to it locally (like it will be in the docker image, once build). I can't seem to get the syntax of the mount command right, though. I'm using VirtualBox, the VM is Linux 2.6 and I'm running Yosemite. Any ideas?